# title border missing in dialog fragment

Tags: android, dialog

I have used dialog fragment several times and the title border always appears but this time it doesn't

this is my code

```
public class DailogBox extends DialogFragment {



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setTitle("title");

    builder.setMessage("message");
    AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();


    return alertdialog;
}
}
```

and this is my style.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I am not sure if the theme is related to the problem

and this is the output i am getting

[image]

Comment: this may be depend on OS version of your device.

Comment: i am using google nexus S api 16

Comment: I have used this phone before to test other apps with dialog fragment and the title border appeared just fine

Comment: @bpA actually you're right , the title border appears again if i change the minimum api level to 11 but i was hoping i could be able to solve for minimum api 8